# Can't closure return a reference?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("foo");
    let f = || &a;
    fn_immut(f);
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn fn_immut<F>(f: F)
               where F: Fn() -> &String
{
    println!("calling Fn closure from fn, {}", f());
}
```

This code can't compile, `rustc` tells me that I should add a `'static` like this:

```rust
fn fn_immut<F>(f: F)
               where F: Fn() -> &'static String
```

I tried to do it, but it still doesn't work. And `rustc` also tells me " this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from".

My question is: in this code,the closure already captures the reference of variable `a` in its scope, why does rustc still tell me that "there is no value for it to be borrowed from"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key message from the compiler is indeed the lack of a lifetime specifier for the closure returning a string. Since the signature defined by the trait `Fn() -> &String` does not have any function parameters, there are no values from which the compiler can infer the lifetime of the returned reference.

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:10:16
   |
10 |     F: Fn() -> &String,
   |                ^ help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime: `&'static`
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
```

Adding `'static` here does not contribute to solving the problem, because in practice the returned string won't have that lifetime. A new lifetime parameter needs to be introduced in `fn_immut`, from which can be transferred to `F`'s constraint.

```
fn fn_immut<'a, F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> &'a String,
```

You can also return a string slice (`&str`) instead of `&String`. The full code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("foo");
    let f = || &*a;
    fn_immut(f);
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn fn_immut<'a, F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> &'a str,
{
    println!("calling Fn closure from fn, {}", f());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e06716f0adcb669f5fd6cfe8a0604e4f)